# Android Studio: ¿Por qué tengo problemas con la muestra del ícono de mi app?

Tags: android, android-studio, icons, icono

**Este es el ícono de mi app:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Primer problema: El ícono de mi app no se muestra**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Segundo problema: El ícono de mi app tiene un fondo blanco (se aprecia en los bordes), el cual no quiero que aparezca**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Mi código xml en el archivo manifests:**

```
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_app"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_app"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

**Mi código xml "@mipmap/ic_app"**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@color/ic_launcher_background"/>
    <foreground android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_app_foreground"/>
</adaptive-icon>
```

**Muchas gracias por leer!**

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente faltan imagenes y algunas otras no son las adecuadas, es importante usar el Asset Studio para generar los iconos para tu aplicación a partir de la imagen del "perrito".

Da botón derecho del "Mouse" para abrir el menú contextual y selecciona `New` > `Vector Asset`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Selecciona la imagen y te mostrará un previo de todas las imágenes a crear para tu proyecto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esta forma se generarán todas las imágenes en los directorios correspondientes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola y muchas gracias por la respuesta Jorge. La imágen de mi app ya estaba cargada con el método que me acabas de explicar. Quizá el problema haya sido que cambié la imágen varias veces a lo largo del proyecto? O será porque creé un "vector_asset" en la carpeta "app" en lugar de la carpeta "src"?